# PHP SQL Working out gaps between visits on a rota

Tags: php, mysql, sql, resultset

I'm having a small problem working out how to write this code.  I have a MySQL query that returns a list of shift dates. Data returned looks like this:

```
id |    date    |  stime   |  etime   | staff | client
------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2014-01-01 | 08:00:00 | 08:30:00 | Dave  | Mary
2  | 2014-01-01 | 08:35:00 | 09:05:00 | Dave  | Clive
3  | 2014-01-01 | 09:17:00 | 09:32:00 | Dave  | Joan
4  | 2014-01-01 | 09:38:00 | 10:08:00 | Dave  | Doris
```

I need to work out the gap between calls. I.e. the gap between `etime` in row 1 AND `stime` in row 2.  The answer should be 5.
I can work out the difference easily using PHP, but cannot work out how to get the: 
`etime` from row 1, the `stime` from row 2, then the `etime` from row 2 and the `stime` from row 3 etc...... and so on...  I guess some kind of alternating function, but don't know.

I do need to point out that the `id` will not will not be contiguous.

I am a newbie to this site and have looked around to see if this question has already been asked.  I apologise if it has. 
Thanks to anyone who can help.

EDIT: @sean has answered the question for me except that the `id` results had to be continuous.  I need to find out how to do a `LEFT JOIN` with non-continuous `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok!  I have worked it out, with help from @Sean and my Auntie Lou :D.  I am sure there is an easier way to do it though.

I have decided to create a new table and copy the information needed into it and generate new id's.  As I am only working on a small database I am not worried about overheads.

Firstly `CREATE` a new `table` (`temp_gaps`), then `SELECT` the required information from the original `table` (`placements`) excluding the `id` column.  This copies the data from the original table to the new one without ID's.  The new table generates a new `auto_increment` ID so everything is now in order in the new table:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_gaps 
(
  `id` mediumint(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `stime` time NOT NULL,
  `etime` time NOT NULL,
  `staff` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `client` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)
engine=memory AS 
  (SELECT date,stime,etime,staff,client 
   FROM   placements 
   ORDER  BY `staff`,`date`,`stime` ASC)
```

Once the information is copied I can then use @Sean previous answer to pull the information, `left_join` the `etime` column and I can then work on the data result in my PHP script.  Once i'm done I just `drop` the table and all is good.

Thanks to Sean for sending me in exactly the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` to join the next row `stime`. Make sure to rename the `t2.stime` so it is not ambiguous.

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       t2.stime as `nxt_row_stime` 
FROM table t1 
LEFT JOIN table t2 
ON t2.id = t1.id+1
```

note: this requires that there is no gaps in the `id` increment.

Comment: Ah... There would be gaps because I am running the query using a `WHERE` statement.

Comment: My mysql query skills are limited/rusty. I know that there is a way to select the next row in the result set, and once I remember how I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Sean. Ill keep digging as well. Appreciate the help 

Comment: I have sorted it @sean.  Thank you for your help.  See my answer below.